# GenericSettingsError when calling Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am saving values to roaming settings using a outlook add-in/office.js and get fllowing error. is there any reason for this ?

> ```
> private saveLoginDetails = async (
>     userName: string,
>     loginResponse: LoginResponse
>   ): Promise<any> => {
>     return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
>       Office.context.roamingSettings.set("username", userName);
>       Office.context.roamingSettings.set("loginResponse", loginResponse);
>       Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(
>         (asyncResult: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
>           console.log(asyncResult);
>           resolve();
>         }
>       );
>     });
>   };
> ```

**Error on Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync function**

```
value: null
status: "failed"
error: OSF.DDA.Error
name: "GenericSettingsError"
message: "An internal error has occurred."
code: 9019
```

here is my manifest

```
   <Host Name="Mailbox" />
 </Hosts>
 <Requirements>
   <Sets>
     <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
   </Sets>
 </Requirements>
```

Comment: What client are you seeing this error? Is it in the rich native Windows desktop client, Mac Outlook, or the web client?

Comment: @[Outlook Add-ins Team] it is web client with chrome(OWA )

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue from our end. Could you try running the following code on the same mailbox and let us know if it fails?

Office.context.roamingSettings.set("username", "username1");
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(
    (asyncResult) => {       
        console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
    });

Comment: I encounter the same issue, I think it's because of my roaming settings is full. But I can't clear it either.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I'm also seeing this error. Roaming settings are empty.